# Change URL of WebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, browser, refresh, reload

I am designing a simple application using c# and it has a web browser in it. I need to either (preferably) refresh the page that is currently inside the broswer, or navigate to a "new" url. I tried `Browser.Url = new Uri("http://www.pandora.com/");` but I get an error when I try to compile it.

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to
>   'System.Uri' c:\users\sean\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\Pandora\Pandora\Form1.cs 51 27 Pandora

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(VS.80).aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode2 I don't see any mistakes in your Uri definition :-?

Comment: It's working fine in my machine.  What's the line 51 in Form1.cs?

Comment: Same here - your sample code looks just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason, it wanted me to write it like this:

```
Browser.Url = new System.Uri("https://www.pandora.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

This works so thats good.